# How to create multiple nodes and relationships in Neo4J with one Cypher / REST query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create multiple nodes (if do not exist yet) and relationships between them (parallel ones, if already exist) with one query.

What would be the best way to do that in Neo4J 2.0?

I tried different ways, but what I've found so far is either to add them pair by pair, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597377/execute-multiple-create-unique-in-one-cypher-query-through-rest-api), [merge on multiple relationships](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-merge.html) (but that seems to work also only by pairs), or through transactions (as [described here](http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/05/new-milestone-release-neo4j-200-m03.html)). The combination of the 2nd and the 3rd option would work fine, but I would just like to limit it to two queries:

1) Create all the nodes (if don't exist yet), get their IDs.

2) Create relationships between them (using IDs obtained in 1).

3) Submit the two queries as statements into transaction, commit.

The only thing is that I'm new to Cypher and don't know how to make a query like that.

Can anybody help, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you add the examples you tried directly to the question, so no one has to follow the links to learn what you tried?

Comment: @MichaelHunger I have a more precise version of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675747/is-it-better-to-make-one-merge-request-in-neo4j-cypher-2-0-or-to-split-it-into-t - maybe you could help? i will then update this question or delete it. Thanks!